# Missing link error using Blue Prism Code Stage

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to figure out how to use the code stage in Blue Prism. I have been trying various simple code snippets, like "Hello World!" and `MessageBox.Show()` in C#.  The check code option shows no errors, but there is an error for the object that says missing link.  Can the code stage be used with `MessageBox.Show()`? Is Blue Prism expecting a link to Decision or Navigate or some other stage?

Comment: Could you provide your code and more details about your use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to run a simple msgbox in BluePrism code stage you need to make sure that three things are present in your Blue Prism object:

- add external reference to .dll files
- add namespace import
- choose language

The same thing has to be done in standard C# programming - in theory we need to to this line of code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

In BluePrism it's hidden in the options of Box on the page "Initialize", with the name of the process name, date of creation, last changed by.

Double click on the object, and the window should appear with the name "Business Object Properties".

Go to the tab "Code options".

You should see the screen with top part called "External Reference" - add there "System.Windows.Forms.dll"

The second part of the screen is called "Namespace Import" - add there "System.Windows.Forms"

Lastly, on the bottom of the screen you can see a combox, where you can choose a language that will be used in this BP Objects. If you'd like to use C#, then that's something you'll have to choose there.

Please see screen below, as I hope it will help you find the necessary things.
[image]

Comment: Ah, or maybe there is no link from start and the end on page "Initialize"?

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I am doing, but it's not working for me.  I'll work on it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Missing link error message indicates that your diagram is missing a link joiner somewhere. If you have a code stage make sure to double check your stage is in fact connected. If you step over a code stage and it is not connected at end point it will execute the code but throw an error saying failed to find link from STAGE NAME etc etc. Most likely some stage you are running does not have the correct link going from it to the next stage. Make sure to click and move your stage as well to double check there is no other stage underneath it or anything by some off chance